# Hibernate custom delete strategy

Tags: java, hibernate, openjpa

I have a project that was recently converted from `OpenJPA` to `Hibernate`.  In replacing the portions of configuration that were specific to `OpenJPA`, I have run across one function I cannot replicate in `Hibernate`.

In `OpenJPA`, we were performing custom deletes by annotating entities with `@Strategy` and providing an instance of an `org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.AbstractStrategy`.  In the `customDelete` method, we were calling a single, shared stored procedure and passing a table name, entity id and a user id performing the action and this procedure would both delete the entity and create an audit log entry.

In `Hibernate`, I can find a number of hooks available, but none quite seem to provide the same functionality. I have looked at the following:

1. @SQLDelete("customer delete query") - This option only allows you access to id, not the table name or user id so custom per class and still lacking info
2. EntityListener class - This option tells you the entity deleted, but requires digging to get at what tables were actually involved and is outside the scope of a single db operation

Are there any other options that are a closer match to the OpenJPA method, or is my best bet going with an `EntityLister` class and doing my own heavy lifting to determine table names?

Answer (score 0):

What about a DAO-Object for your persistency Class in which you can define custom DB methods. Here is an example DAO which was generated with HiberObjects. The generated methods can be defined as desired by removing the @generated comment.

```
package de.cw.minifigfinder.dao;

import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;

import de.cw.minifigfinder.model.UIValues;

/**
 * @generated
 */
public class UIValuesDAO {

private static final String ID = "MINIFIGFINDER";

/**
 * @generated
 */
public UIValuesDAO() {
}

/**
 * @generated
 */
private javax.persistence.EntityManager getSession() {
    return de.cw.minifigfinder.util.HibernateHelper.getInstance()
            .getEntityManager();
}

public Long create() {
    UIValues object = new UIValues();
    object.setValuesID(ID);
    if (object == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("object");
    javax.persistence.EntityManager em = getSession();
    EntityTransaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        em.persist(object);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        throw e; // or display error message
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
    return object.getId();
}


/**
 * @generated
 */
public void delete(de.cw.minifigfinder.model.UIValues object) {
    if (object == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("object");
    getSession().remove(object);
}
```

}